# как в телеграм боте сделать жирным определенную часть текста,

Tags: python, telegram-bot, markdown

[image: вот что выводит]

когда я пытаюсь выделить жирным переменную он ругается когда переменных нет все хорошо

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "*Жирный*", parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

Comment: Если ответ помог, поставь галочку возле моего ответа